# EventListeners within a loop [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have few pieChart objects stored in shapes array... I want to add event listeners for each of the object. I tried doing it like this:

```
var tempS = shapes.slice();
        
for(var i=0; i<shapes.length; i++)
{
    var S = tempS.pop();
    if(S.name == 'pieChart')
    {
        document.getElementById(S.id).addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            alert(S.id);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that, even when I click on pieChart2 (id->2), it will always give the id->1 (as it pops last). Kindly explain this behavior and what can possibly be the efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `var` declarations have function scope (or global if declared in the global scope), your code is equivalent to:

```
var tempS = shapes.slice(),
    i, S;

for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    S = tempS.pop();
    if (S.name == 'pieChart') {
        document.getElementById(S.id).addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            alert(S.id);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Now, it is clear that `S` is scoped outside of the `for` block, and as the event handlers will be triggered after the loop finishes, `S` will have the value of the last iteration.

You need to create a new scope, either through a callback factory (as in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1331430)) or an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), to trap the current `S` value of the iteration.

```
var tempS = shapes.slice();

for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) { (function() {//introduces a new scope
    var S = tempS.pop(); //now S is scoped inside this iteration's IIFE
    if (S.name == 'pieChart') {
        document.getElementById(S.id).addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            alert(S.id); //will reference the IIFE scope's S
        }, false);
    }
}()); }
```

You can do this in many alternative ways as well, for example, using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var tempS = shapes.slice();
shapes.forEach(function(S) { //S is now scoped in the forEach callback scope
    if (S.name == 'pieChart') {
        document.getElementById(S.id).addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            alert(S.id);
        }, false);
    }
});
```

Note that this will change the iteration order, but I believe it won't matter for this use case.

---

In ES6 it will be possible to use `let` to create block-scoped variables:

```
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    let S = tempS.pop(); //scoped inside the `for` block
    if (S.name == 'pieChart') {
        document.getElementById(S.id).addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            alert(S.id);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

I'm leaving this approach here for future readers, as [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is not ready for production yet. Most recent browsers do have experimental implementations though (see [ES6 compat table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/)).

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Using underscore.js :

```
_.each(shapes, function(s) {
    if(s.name === 'pieChart') {
        document.getElementById(s.id).addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            alert(target.id);
        });
    }
});
```

To explain the behaviour of your code, you have to remember that javascript uses function scope as opposed to block scope. So since your defining S outside of the eventListener callback function the reference to S inside the callback will be the current value of S, which after the loops execution will be the last pieChart object in the shapes array.

Answer (score 1):

Inside callback, use `this` instead of accessing element by `id` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
e.target.id
```

instead

```
S.id
```

in event listener

Comment: you mean document.getElementById(e.target.id).addEventListener(....... ?? :S

Comment: I mean alert(e.target.id)

Comment: That's not gonna affect the working of the code! alert is just displaying the value...